# Ember.js: when using {{action}}, how to target a specific controller?

Tags: ember.js

I put my question in a code example here:

http://jsbin.com/urukil/12/edit

See, I can use a `{{action}}` (which is placed in a child view) with `target` option to trigger an event in `ApplicationView` or `ApplicationController` or `ChildView`, only except the `ChildController` which is the one I truly wanted.

According the document, if no `target` specified, the event itself should handled in corresponding controller, in my case, which is should be `ChildController`. But why this action always lookup in `ApplicationController`? Did I miss something obviously important?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `this.controllerFor('')` to call different controller event. A working example is given below.

JS:

```
/// <reference path="Lib/ember.js" />
var app = Ember.Application.create()
app.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('post')

});
app.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function () { 
        return { "firstName": "amit", "lastName": "pandey" }
    }
});
app.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    Address: "House no 93-B",
    fullName: function () {
        return this.get("model.firstName") + " " + this.get("model.lastName")
    }.property("model.firstName", "model.lastName"),
    actions: {
        submit: function (name) {

            this.controllerFor('post').send('handleclick')

        },
        makeMeUpper:function()
        {
            alert('calling application controller Event');
           this.set("model.firstName",this.get("model.firstName").toUpperCase())
        }


    }



});


app.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model:function()
    {
        return user;


    }


});
app.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    Hello: "afa",
    handleclick: function ()
    {
        alert('calling post controller Event');

        this.controllerFor('application').send('makeMeUpper');
    }


});


var user = [
    {
        id: "1",
        Name: "sushil "

    },
    {
        id: "2",
        Name: "amit"

    }

];
```

//hbs

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars">
      <button {{action submit firstName}}>CLICK HERE TO CALL Post controller event</button>
       {{input type="text" action= "makeMeUpper" value=firstName }}     

       {{#if check}}
      No Record Exist

       {{else}}
       {{firstName}}{{lastName}}
       {{/if}}
       {{#linkTo 'post'}}click {{/linkTo}}
       {{outlet}}
   </script>
        <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="post">

            <button {{action hanleclick}}>Click here to call application controller event</button>
        </script>
```

Comment: Yes.i tested this on latest version of Ember.js

Comment: Nope. Using `controllerFor` inside controllers will throw deprecated message. Refer https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1896

Comment: To get the other controllers instance, you have to use `needs` in controller and you can use `controllerFor` in routes.

Comment: @selvagsz is correct. `needs` is the preferred to do this going forward per documentation. He provided the solution below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16901725

Answer (score 18):

You can use [`needs`](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/) to call a action on different controller...

```
 App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['child'],
  doSomething: function() {
  alert("From ApplicationController");
  }
});
```

And the target can be specified as "controllers.child" from the template

```
<p {{action doSomething target="controllers.child"}}>Blah blah</p>
```

Here is your working fiddle...

http://jsbin.com/agusen/1/edit

Comment: BTW, according to the guide, view will find action in **current controller**, since this view not involved with any **state transition**, the **current controller** is always `ApplicationController`. So if you want use another controller, you'd better use `needs` attribute to manage controller dependencies by yourself.

Comment: This is the preferred method going forward. Also, if you need to work with nested folders, this is a solution I provided in a different post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29269015/499700

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the view class does not change the current controller. Since you are calling the view from the Application template, it remains in the ApplicationController.

### Emberjs.com guides on render:

```
{{render}} does several things:

When no model is provided it gets the singleton instance of the corresponding controller
```

Simply changing your code from a view to a render call seems to do the trick:

```
Trigger ApplicationController
</p>
{{render 'child'}}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, render can also help me this out, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Since controllerFor is getting deprecated, the correct way to do this now is to specify needs in the controller, retrieve it from the controllers list, and then send it there. Example:

```
App.SomeController = Em.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['other'],
  actions: {
    sayHello: function () {
    console.log("Hello from inside SomeController.");
    this.get('controllers.other').send('helloAgain');
    }
  }
});

App.OtherController = Em.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    helloAgain: function () {
      console.log("Hello again from inside OtherController!");
    }
  }

});
```

EDIT: oops... Looks like someone already posted this answer in essence.  Will revise if needed.