# Accessing Ember-CLI Nested Controllers

Tags: javascript, ember.js, nested, ember-cli, controllers

This is my directory structure:

```
controllers/
---- restaurant/
    ----items.js
---- index.js
---- restaurant.js
```

And my router declaration:

```
this.route("restaurants",{
path: "/restaurants"
});

this.resource("restaurant", {
path: "/restaurants/:restaurant_id"
}, function() {
    this.resource("items", {
    path: "/items"
    });
});
```

My Items controller (located in restaurants/items.js) begins with the following:

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ["restaurant"],
    restaurant: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.restaurant.model')
```

and is then followed by an action to add the item under hte restaurant.

However, I keep getting hte error saying "restaurant" needs to be added to "needs":

> ReferenceError: (generated items controller)#needs does not include `restaurant`. To access the restaurant controller from (generated items controller), (generated items controller) should have a `needs` property that is an array of the controllers it has access to

This is my setup (Ember-CLI 0.1.2 with Ember 1.7) - As i'm using the fireplace adapter to work with firebase, I don't think it supports upgrading Ember (from what I've tried).

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.7.0"
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.10"
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0"
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.2"
DEBUG: Fireplace  : 0.2.9"
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

I've tried the other Stackoverflow answers (e.g. [How to communicate between controllers in Ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862973/how-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-ember-js?rq=1)) but they don't seem to help.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: strange, everything looks good. Is ember-cli watching for changes properly (sublime text sometimes locks it up). Perhaps try restarting ember-cli.  Do you have the ember inspector? Make sure the current route is using the correct controller?

Comment: Hi aaron, thanks for the response. I use Atom and not Sublime, and I have reinstalled ember-cli and have restarted the sever numerous times but the issue persists. It's quite strange - the correct model is being loaded according to Ember Inspector as well. Also, I've tried it out on two different OS (Windows + Mac) on separate computers with the same repository and the issue persists. One uses 0.1.5 version of ember and the other 0.1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Ember-CLI v0.2.1 + Ember v1.10.0 (could work for earlier versions; but I haven't tried), this is how you do it:

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ["restaurant/items"],
    ...
```

To access actions, you'd do this:

```
actions: {
    myAction: function(arg1, arg2) {
      this.get('controllers.restaurant/item').send('someItemActionYouDefine', arg1, arg2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're Items controller needs to be in the subfolder `restaurant`. Move it up a level and see if that fixes the issue.